# Refresh Access bound form internal field list

Tags: vba, ms-access

A little background first: I have a form in Access bound to a table. I was fighting an annoying error earlier where all calls to the `Format(...)` function threw a `type mismatch` error, regardless of what it was given as arguments. More perplexing was that the error only occurred when the form was open - in the immediate window I could type:

```
? Format(#17 March 2015#, "dd MMM yyyy")
```

If the form was closed, firing this code would return the expected result. When it was open, it threw `type mismatch`. Confusing.

I eventually tracked the issue down - a field in the table bound to the form was named **Format**, and this was *shadowing* the `Format()` function, so VBA was attempting to treat the table field as a function and erroring.

I closed the form, went into the table design and renamed the Format column to RequestFormat, expecting the issue to spirit away. Unfortunately, VBA seems to have a thing for rigidly clinging on to things forever once defined, and still maintains an entry for the now non-existent table field that continues to shadow the `Format()` function. An entry, I might add, that also cannot be referenced as a table field either because any attempts to call it as such prompts Access to tell me that it can't find a field named `Format`. Because it doesn't exist.

So, somehow I need to get Access to rebuild its internal list of fields for the bound form and get rid of the now-deceased Format field. Any ideas?

To prove that I'm not crazy, here's the intellisense in the IDE when `Format` is entered on a brand new form bound to the same table:

[image]

And here it is on my original form, still showing the recently-deceased Format property that shouldn't still be there:

[image]

Comment: Already tried: Closing/reopeing the database doesn't fix it, neither does Compact & Repair or decompiling.

Comment: Does the form use a query as its Record Source?  If so, does that query still reference a field named *Format*?

Comment: No, it's bound straight to the table. I idiot-checked all of those kind of things before posting (there's nothing on the form called Format - no controls, variables or anything) :)

Comment: This sounds weird ... as if Access still remembers the field which no longer exists in the table.  As a long shot, I would save a copy of the revised table under a different name.  Then if you change the form's Record Source to that table copy, does it still think there is a field named *Format*?

Comment: @HansUp Aha, think you've cracked it. Changing the record source to a copy of the table removed the errant Format property. And changing it back didn't make it reappear. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: (worth noting a copy of the table isn't necessary - changing the record source of the form to any other table and changing back, or just removing it and putting it back in, fixes it)

Comment: Fair enough.  I wanted to keep the other fields the same, just to avoid any other complications.  But apparently that wasn't necessary.  Meanwhile I still don't understand why the problem happened it in the first place; it just seems bizarre.  By the way, are you Kai the blues guy who worked for a Colorado auto hauler?

Comment: Yeah, it was a bizarre problem. VBA does like to hang on to things sometimes. And nope, that's not me. I'm in the UK, and I don't think anyone who knows me would let me get behind the wheel of a truck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can make Access "forget" about the field which no longer exists.

Save a copy of your current table with a new name.  Then use that new name in the form's Record Source.

(*Note: Kai reported any old table change worked --- it doesn't require the same table structure.*)

If Access no longer thinks there is a field named *Format*, change the Record Source again back to the old table name and see if it has still forgotten about the *Format* field.

Comment: Yeah, copying the table isn't necessary (and probably undesirable if it's a big table). Changing it to some other table will make all the references break, but they'll be fixed again once you change it back.

Comment: For a large table, I would paste the copy as structure only.  But since it doesn't even have to be the same table structure anyway, I guess that's a moot point.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can sidestep the namespace collision problem by fully qualifying the VBA `Format` function, like this:

```
VBA.Format(#17 March 2015#, "dd MMM yyyy")
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to my core problem (just discovered myself but using `Strings.Format` instead of `VBA.Format`), upvoted but going to wait to see if there's an answer to the question regarding 'rebuilding' the field list before accepting :)